# SignalR and Twitter Streaming API

Tags: c#, .net, twitter, signalr-hub

Right now I've got a interval set up to pull statuses from Twitter. Basically the client does a get to my server and my server goes to Twitter for the statuses.

Is there an example anywhere to where I can use SignalR with the Twitter streaming api?

If I was to use the streaming Twitter api does this mean that I would have to host the SignalR hub in a windows service?

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to pull statuses ever 30 seconds from my server to the Twitter server and once received push the statuses to the client?